# How to remove horizontal greenish flickering bars on pycharm and java applications?

Tags: graphics

When i run this in Pycharm:
[Morpholib mathematical animations engine](https://github.com/morpho-matters/morpholib)
Or this
[Shrdlu 3d version](https://hci.stanford.edu/winograd/shrdlu/download/javashrdlu.zip)
by running the file shrdlu.bat in the unzipped file-set, the running windows are covered in green flickering hotizontal bars like shown here:
[green flicker issue post](https://github.com/psychopy/psychopy/issues/3228)

System:
Acer Nitro 5,
Windows 11 home version 23h2,
Intel UHD Graphics and driver-version 27.20.100.8280

How can i fix this?